# How to log only heavy ad intervention errors with Sentry?

Tags: javascript, ads, sentry, google-ad-manager

Now i am using following config:

```
<script src="https://browser.sentry-cdn.com/7.35.0/bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-uwCOEtT/vtuzGz5QiQB6J1L3YFYSbznHZGi3B5Vc6+bnyGS3O9nnDfh6dCvLrQ7X" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://browser.sentry-cdn.com/7.35.0/reportingobserver.min.js" integrity="sha384-IpI7+T3lCLEWg9wsg2Mjw8tT6/6rUrOUc8AXGFSSOuuuYXWzbwOv1thNsthhzvN+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        Sentry.init({
            dsn: "https://xxx@xxxx.ingest.sentry.io/xxx",
            sampleRate: 1,
            tracesSampleRate: 1,
            integrations: [new Sentry.Integrations.ReportingObserver(
                {
                    types: ['intervention']
                }
            )],
        });
    </script>
```

And Sentry logs JS "Errors" + "Intervention" messages just fine, except one moment.
There are no so called "heavy ad interventions" (https://developer.chrome.com/blog/heavy-ad-interventions/) issues in logs.
But I am sure 100% that that kind of errors happens, because I saw them in my console.

I think that the problem could be that those "heavy ad intervention" errors appears only after some time after page DOM was loaded.

Anyone tried to catch those "heavy ad intervention" error with Sentry? How?

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap the code in a try-catch block and send the error to Sentry:

```
try {
// Your code here
} catch (error) {
Sentry.captureException(error);
}
```